# Change a view margins programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I have a RecyclerView that has 250dp bottom margin
And I need to set the bottom margin programmatically to 0dp then set it back to 250dp, I have tried this but it's working just to set it 0dp and it doesn't work setting it to 250dp back:

```
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) linearLayoutRv.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(0,0,0,250); // params.setMargins(0,0,0,0); at first
                linearLayoutRv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

There's some unnecessary things but here's the xml file :

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            //textview
          
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            //some buttons
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set margins programatically, you set value in pixels, not dp. Source of LayoutParams:

```
         /**
         * Sets the margins, in pixels. A call to {@link android.view.View#requestLayout()} needs
         * to be done so that the new margins are taken into account. Left and right margins may be
         * overridden by {@link android.view.View#requestLayout()} depending on layout direction.
         * Margin values should be positive.
         *
         * @param left the left margin size
         * @param top the top margin size
         * @param right the right margin size
         * @param bottom the bottom margin size
         *
         * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ViewGroup_MarginLayout_layout_marginLeft
         * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ViewGroup_MarginLayout_layout_marginTop
         * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ViewGroup_MarginLayout_layout_marginRight
         * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ViewGroup_MarginLayout_layout_marginBottom
         */
        public void setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
            leftMargin = left;
            topMargin = top;
            rightMargin = right;
            bottomMargin = bottom;
            mMarginFlags &= ~LEFT_MARGIN_UNDEFINED_MASK;
            mMarginFlags &= ~RIGHT_MARGIN_UNDEFINED_MASK;
            if (isMarginRelative()) {
                mMarginFlags |= NEED_RESOLUTION_MASK;
            } else {
                mMarginFlags &= ~NEED_RESOLUTION_MASK;
            }
        }
```

You need convert your dp to pixels:

```
Int yourDP = 250
Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
    yourDP,
    r.getDisplayMetrics()
);
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) linearLayoutRv.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0,0,0,(int) px); // params.setMargins(0,0,0,0); at first
            linearLayoutRv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setMargins` accepts values not in `dp` (density independent pixels) unit but in `px` (pixel) unit.

You must convert your value of 250 to `dp` before passing it to the `params` object.

```
Context context = ...; // place 'this' if you are in an Activity or 'requireContext()' if you are in a Fragment
Resources res = context.getResources();
float dp250 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 250, res.getDisplayMetrics());

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) linearLayoutRv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, dp250);
linearLayoutRv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

`dp250` will result in a different number of pixels on different devices. It depends on the resolution and physical screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [`MotionLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout).
Just convert parent `ConstraintLayout` to `MotionLayout`, create `MotionScene`
and in code use [`transitionToEnd()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout#transitionToEnd()) and [`transitionToStart()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout#transitionToStart())

[example](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples)

Answer (score 0):

it was working but in pixels, so i added this method:

```
public static int convertDpToPixel(int dp, Context context){
    return dp * ((int) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

and changed this:

```
params.setMargins(0,0,0,convertDpToPixel(250,getContext()));
```